# Did you get my "email" or Did you get my "mail"?

Tags: differences, email

I am getting confused whenever I tried to use email or mail while in the conversation or in written form. For example, which one is correct?

> Did you get my email?

or

> Did you get my mail?

Please suggest which one is correct.

Comment: "Did you get my message?" would be a valid alternative to "Did you get my email?".  "Did you get my mail?" implies that the postal service was employed.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I'd like to advise you to visit [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think one of them is "correct" (and the other presumably not?)

As far as I am concerned I use "mail" and "email" interchangeably - I'm more likely to say "mail".

[It may be relevant that I speak British English, where we use "mail" only as a mass term when referring to postal services. To me "a mail" can only mean "an email", and nothing else.]

Comment: In American English, we never say "a mail" for postal mail or for email.  But you can say "I sent you an email." "Mail" almost exclusively means postal mail, and "message" can be an email, a text, or some kind of instant message service, if anyone still uses them.

Comment: That is different, then. In the UK "mail" almost exclusively means email, except in certain set phrases such as "Royal mail" and "In the mail". I wouldn't refer to a delivery of letters, or the pile of letters on the mat, as "mail", and they are delivered by a postman (or postwoman, or, now a Post Office worker) not a mailman.

Comment: @Colin--In the US, mail used to be delivered by a mailman or a postman, but due to gender neutrality, we are encouraged to say "letter carrier" or "mail carrier."

Answer (score 1):

"*Did you my email?*" is for email.

"*Did you get my mail?*" is for postal mail.

It is still customary to refer to email as email, distinguished from regular mail.

Comment: It may be customary for you, @jimm101; but I don't think I would _ever_ refer to a letter sent through the post as "a mail". So "my mail" and "my email" would both mean and email for me.

Comment: Did you get my letter?  Old school but accurate.

Comment: @ColinFine yup ... I'm just saying it's customary to refer to email as email, to distinguish that from regular (postal) mail. I didn't comment on regular mail conventions there. :-)

Comment: In the US, "Did you get my letter?" means that I sent you a letter via the post office.  "Did you get my mail?" means I'm on vacation and I asked you to collect my letters for me so they wouldn't be sitting in the mailbox all week.  If you sent an email message, you could say "Did you get my email?"

Comment: @StevenLittman I agree... in the US I've never used mail for email.